# Missing Shared Library

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, shared-libraries

- libc6 2.17-97
- locales 2.17-97
- simplescreenrecorder

Which I have done.

Upon executing `simplescreenrecorder`, I receive the following output:

```
simplescreenrecorder: error while loading shared libraries: libavformat.so.53: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After running `updatedb`, when I `locate` the file, I get:

```
/home/NAME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.53
/home/NAME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.53.21.1
/home/NAME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libavformat.so.53
/home/NAME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libavformat.so.53.21.1
/home/NAME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.53
/home/NAME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.53.21.1
```

Comment: Is the library in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/pathTo.so

Answer (score 1):

As suggest in comments, if you have installed manually some libraries, make sure to run:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Then, if not works, use:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/pathTo.so
```